# Update not working i can't find my error

Tags: php

My update script is not working.. I don't know what im missing..
but i can't update the table ... Went to w3school to know about the update in php but still it wont work...
-noob coder-

```
<?php 
include 'Core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'Includes/Overall/overallheader.php';
?>
<h1>Update School Year and Semester</h1>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234","database3");
// Check connection
$sy = $_POST['school_year'];
$sem = $_POST['semester'];
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) )
{
$sql = "UPDATE `activesys` SET `activeschoolyear` = '$sy' AND `activesemester` = '$sem'";
$exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>

<li>
    School Year:<br />
    <input type="text" name="school_year">
</li>
<li>
    Semester:<br />
    <input type="text" name="semester">
</li>
<li>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</li>

</ul>
</form>


<?php
include 'Includes/Overall/overallfooter.php'; 
?>
```

Comment: You can't mix calls to `mysqli()` and `mysql()` - just use `mysqli()`. BTW, if you want good reference material use the [PHP](http://www.php.net) site.

Comment: What error you getting ? *Note:* Never ever refer to w3schools tutorials, it has many glitches in it which miss directs the users.

Comment: you have to put `comma separated` values in update query..
like 
`update table_name set field=value1,field2=value2.....`
you have put `and` instead of `comma`..

Comment: i'm a little confused... so i have to use a comma then replace it again with and? like this?
$sql = "UPDATE activesys SET activeschoolyear = '$sy' AND activesemester = '$sem'";

Answer (score 1):

Even though its not directly realated:

Please make sure to escape Request data that you load from $_POST or $_GET by using mysql_escape_string . Otherwise it would be easy to inject SQL in your query, which would allow to run harmfull sql in your system, like deleting the database or manipulating the data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You have missed where condition in update query .. try this

```
  UPDATE table_name
    SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
    WHERE some_column=some_value

$sql = "UPDATE `activesys` SET `activeschoolyear` = '$sy' AND `activesemester` = '$sem'"  WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you mix `mysqli` and `mysql`. Second, `mysql_query`/`mysqli_query` have two parameters. Third, your sql is not right.

So, change your `$exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`

to `$exec = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

change your sql to :

```
$sql = "UPDATE `activesys` SET `activeschoolyear` = '$sy' , `activesemester` = '$sem'";
```

but you didn't have a where condition here, if in your table you have set an 
anto-increment key and set it to primary key, you could add some condition end of you sql,otherwise it will 
update all your records.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `activesys` SET `activeschoolyear` = '$sy' , `activesemester` = '$sem' where id={$id}"
```

$id is one recod from you table.

this should work for you excute an update..

Comment: I did Change it just now but still its not updating.. is my Sql composition right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

1) use "action" attribute of the  tag

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

2) check whether your form has beensubmitted :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

3) Use WHERE condition in your sql query. You final query should look like this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234","database3");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    }

    $query = "
       UPDATE `activesys` 
       SET `activeschoolyear` = '$sy',`activesemester` = '$sem'
       WHERE `columnName` = `columnValue`
    ";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
```

Comment: i dont know what will i put on the Where statement..
because the table activesys has only 2 columns the activeschoolyear and the activesemester